# How add python if statement to onchange event in html

Tags: python, html, bottle

### Hello

My example string with html code:

```
x =  '''<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="firstname1">
        <input type="text" name="firstname2">
      <input type="text" name="txt"  onchange="myFunction()">   
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<script>
function myFunction() {
        ''' --->python code--->if request.forms.get('txt'):
return x= "ok"
'''

}
</script>'''
```

How can i do something like that?

all this things need to happend before submit

Comment: You cannot use Python for this. Use Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'''<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="firstname1">
<input type="text" name="firstname2">
<input type="text" name="txt"  onchange="myFunction()">   
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<script>
function myFunction() {
 {}
}
</script>'''.format(THE PYTHON CODE THAT EVALUATE TO TEXT)
```